# What is the code to write for one to many relationship in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I made two tables, `governorate` and `district`. I need to choose a specific governorate and get a specific area related to the chosen governorate. What is the right query?

(governorate table)

```
SELECT GoverID, GoverName 
FROM dbo.Governorate 
ORDER BY GoverID
```

(district table)

```
SELECT GoverID, DistName 
FROM dbo.Area 
ORDER BY DistName
```

The primary key is `GoverID` in `governorate` table and the foreign key is `GoverID` in `district` table.

Comment: Have you covered joins in your course?

Comment: @P.Salmon no i haven't

Comment: @Morten ok, i will